# async.filter is calling callback before all iterators finish

Tags: javascript, async.js

I am using [caolan's async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). I'm confused why the callback is getting called before all of the iterators are done. When I run the following code:

```
  async.filter(matched_objects.fields, function(item, callback) {
      console.log('checking field: ' + item.id);
      if(item.id == 130 || item.id == 131) {
        console.log('calling field true: ' + item.id);
        callback(true);
      } 
      callback(false);
    },
    function(fieldResults) {
      console.log('fieldsResults.length=' + fieldResults.length);
    });
```

I get the following output:

```
checking field: 130 
calling field true: 130 
fieldsResults.length=1 
checking field: 131
calling field true: 131
```

It doesn't make any sense to me that the console.log in the callback is getting called before the second `results.fields` item is checked in the filter loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `callback(false)` is called everytime, even if you hit the `if` condition. The right approach would be to add a `return` statement:

```
if(item.id == 130 || item.id == 131) {
  console.log('calling field true: ' + item.id);
  return callback(true);  // now you won't call callback(false) everytime
} 
callback(false);
```

And you can even shorten the filter by saying:

```
callback(item.id == 130 || item.id == 131);
```

Comment: Yep - I've learned this lesson a couple times over since this post.

Comment: In your second example that is just the return statement, where do you put your callback? And why do you need a `return`? If you wanted to avoid the if/else for the sake of being brief, wouldn't you need to do something like `callback(item.id == 130 || item.id == 131)`? Sorry, I know this is years old, there just aren't a lot of examples on the internet about this method. Thanks.

Comment: You're right @thomas. I've edited my answer to add that clarity.

Answer (score 0):

After more experimentation I've discovered the problem was the callback(false); line. apparently this caused the filter to exit. I guess this makes sense since it forces the callback to be called.